# How to Solve this Fokker-Planck Equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I need to solve this Fokker-Planck equation in Mathematica and my attempt to perform this integration is above:

[image: The Fokker-Planck equation that I need to solve.]

My first attempt is above:

```
a = .3;
µ = .1;
c = .2;
σ = 0.1;
b1 = -a s i;
b2 = a s i - µ i + c i - c s i - c i i;
eqns = D[p[s, i, t], t] == 0.5 σ^2 D[p[s, i, t], {i, 2}] - D[b1 p[s, i, t],{s}] - D[(b2 p[s, i, t] p[s, i, t]), {i}];
DSolve[{eqns, p[s, i, 0] == DiracDelta[.3, .7], Limit[p[s, i, t], s -> Infinity] == 0, Limit[p[s, i, t], i -> Infinity] == 0, Limit[D[p[s, i, t],s], s-> Infinity] == 0, Limit[D[p[s, i, t], s], i -> Infinity] == 0}, {p[s,i, t]}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

But I get nothing from this code. I'm quite sure that's all wrong, How could I solve this equation?

Comment: What is the `DiracDelta` supposed to do? It does not depend on any of the variables...

Comment: It’s a initial condition, the values of $S$ and $I$ in the time $t=t_{0}$

Comment: `DiracDelta[x1, x2]` is a distribution that, sloppily said, equals infinity when its arguments `x1 == x2 == 0`. You just have numbers in there. `DiracDelta[.3, .7]` will forever and ever equal zero.

Comment: How can I adjust this initial condition to make it work? Taking away the Dirac Delta?

Comment: Maybe you meant `DiracDelta[s - 3/10]*DiracDelta[i - 7/10]`? We can't help with the implementation of the math if you can't tell us the math :) Maybe add the equations you want to solve in LaTeX form to the question, in addition to the code?

Comment: I tried, The stack exchange doesn't allow me to post the equations in latex form because it looks like a code with impropoer formating :/

Comment: A photo then? The most important copyable thing is code, which you already have.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I've added the picture with the equations, I hope this make the problem clear :)

Comment: I'm skeptical that an analytical solution exists for `DSolve` to find.  Have you tried solving just the drift terms as two ODEs for `s'[t]` and `i'[t]`?  You might need to resort to numerical solution with `NDSolve`.  Also, based on the assumption that this is some kind of SI epidemic model, should there be boundary conditions at `s==0` and `i==0` instead of `-Infinity`?

Comment: @ChrisK Nice guess, In fact that a epidemic model. $p$ is a probability density function, so ideed, the boundary conditions are nice.

Comment: The equation in the picture is linear, and the code contains a nonlinear term `- D[(b2 p[s, i, t] p[s, i, t]), {i}]`